# Template class method declaration failed

Tags: c++, class, templates, methods, syntax-error

I have a class defined as it follows:

```
template <typename T> class list
{
  private:
  struct node
  {
    T val;
    node *next;
  } *origin;

  node* iterate(node *first,node *last);

  (...) code      
};
```

With it's function method defined here:

```
template <typename T>
node* list<T>::iterate(node *first,node *last)
{
  while(first->next!=last)
  {
    first = first->next;
  }
  return first;
}
```

Since the class is using the template feature, everything is written in a header.

The problem is that when I try to compile it gives me these errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
error C2923: 'list' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
```

All these 4 errors indicate at this line:

```
template <typename T>
node* list<T>::iterate(node *first,node *last)
```

In all cases the function is called this way from within the class:

```
 node* aux = iterate(origin,origin);
```

What is the problem here? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outside the definition of the `list` class template, `node` is not a known type. Hence, an explicit scoping has to be specified for the return type. It is not needed for the argument type since by that time, the scope is known to be `list<T>`.

Use

```
template <typename T>
typename list<T>::node* list<T>::iterate(node *first,node *last)
{
  while(first->next!=last)
  {
    first = first->next;
  }
  return first;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler sees `node *` on the line:

```
node* list<T>::iterate(node *first,node *last)
```

it doesn't know what you are talking about: since it can't understand the first token then it doesn't get as far as realizing that this is supposed to be a typename looked up under the context of `list<T>`.

In C++03 the fix is to manually specify the scope (and the fact that it is a typename, since it's a dependent name):

```
typename list<T>::node* list<T>::iterate(node *first,node *last)
```

In C++11 new syntax was added to avoid this problem, where the return type comes afterwards so that unqualified name lookup can happen properly:

```
auto list<T>::iterate(node *first,node *last) -> node*
{
    // ...
```